# Why shouldn't the function within a function of an onclick-event have parentheses?

Tags: javascript, callback, onclick

I was battling with this problem for a while:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="barPlot(function1())">
<input type="submit" onclick="barPlot(function2())">
```

Where I tried to, via an onclick event, allow my "barPlot()" function to pick data from various functions.

The result of this in my barPlot function which looked like this...:

```
function barPlot(callback) {

    var myData = callback();

    }
```

...was "callback is not a function".

When I finally tried this (removing the end-parentheses in the call) it worked:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="barPlot(function1)">
<input type="submit" onclick="barPlot(function2)">
```

Why is that?

(If someone has some additional critique of my way of doing this, then you are allowed to freely mention it. This is practice for me).

Comment: Not related to your question, but since you mentioned critique: I recommend using modern event handling (`addEventListener` and such) rather than `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers, which require that the functions they refer to be globals. (And then, of course, making the functions non-global, since the global namespace is *really* crowded.)

Comment: Thanks for that mention. Do you have any good sources that I could be looking at? My struggle as a non-programmer, despite having read books like "JavaScript the good parts", is that I have absolutely no idea of what damage I'm causing and how I should structure my code, especially when it grows large.
(This handling of global functions is especially hard for me: How should I keep them away from the global namespace at the same time as I should be able to use them at the same time) - This just as a mention of how from scratch I'm currently working :)

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) is a good community-edited site for JavaScript, DOM, and related information, generally fairly accurate (but again, community-edited so sometimes errors creep in and don't get fixed for a while). The page on `addEventListener` is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if you add the parenteshes you are making a call to that function and giving the outer function the value returned by the execution of the inner one.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you have to provide a function as a callback, but if you write parentheses, you don't provide a function. Instead your execute the written function (due to the parentheses) and provide the value returned by it.